# Dollars in the “Hot Network Questions” get mistakenly loaded by MathJax.

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, hot-questions-list

I've noticed that dollars in the “Hot Network Questions” get mistakenly loaded by MathJax, e.g.

[image]

---

**(Feb. 23, 2017, AK)** The bug is still at large, as can be seen here:
[image]

Comment: Odd. [The question title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215029/6354) actually has two `$$$` blocks, which may have outsmarted the block on questions with MathJax in their titles from appearing in the Hot Questions list ([see MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237475/214632)). (Then again, this block may only be set up for questions coming from MathJax-enabled sites, which tex.SE isn't.) The title actually appears as intended when viewed on [tex.SE's Hot Question list](http://i.stack.imgur.com/txpOn.png).

Comment: As an aside: this is interesting, as I seem to recall seeing this question a few days ago where the `$$$` were ***not*** rendered. (Or, possibly, the similar question about remapping `$$`.)  Could this have *anything* to do with the new update of MathJax?

Comment: @ArthurFischer My guess is that LaTeX-containing titles are suppressed only from the sites that have MathJax enabled, but I am not going to watch the Hot List long enough to find out.

Comment: @Behaviour that is correct; suppression only occurs for sites with MathJax enabled. A possible solution could be extending MathJax to exclude DOM elements from processing, similar to how it already allows specifying which elements to only process, via its [`elements` option](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html).  Will look into that.

Comment: There is an older related bug report, which is not marked as ([meta-tag:status-completed]): [Hot network questions incorrectly use MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13619). Still I am not sure whether it is a duplicate, since this one has several consecutive dollars.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I voted to close as dupe the other one. It is about the same issue. And at least with the update this post clearly includes the other one.

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Ping.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you for the ping!

Comment: @Jarrod: No, thank you for the quick solution!

Answer (score 8):

Wow, when I last looked at this, I completely missed the "how to exclude an element from processing" in MathJax's documentation.

The [`tex2jax` configuration](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html) has an `ignoreClass` option that does exactly what we need:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
        ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore"
    }
});
```

I've added the `.tex2jax_ignore` class to the Hot Network Question's container element, which looks to have stopped the processing.

This fix has been built out.